# inequality method of solution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Im looking for an efficent method of solving the following inequality: $$\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right)^2-7 \left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|+ 10 <0$$

I've tried first determining when the absolute value will be positive or negative etc, and than giving it the signing in accordance to range it is in, bur it turned out to be quite complex and apperently also wrong. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $t \equiv \frac{x-3}{x+1} > 0$, the solution to $ t^2 - 7t + 10 <0$ is $ 2<t<5$. (Factor the quadratic.)

When $t < 0$, the solution to $ t^2 + 7t + 10 <0$ is $ -2<t<-5$.

On the $t < 0$ branch, we need to solve $-2 < \frac{x-3}{x+1} < 5$. We break this up into two possibilities, $x < -1$ and $x > -1$, because when we multiply through by $x+1$ in the  $x < -1$case we have to flip the sense of the the inequality.

When  $x < -1$ we then get on one side $-2(x+1) < x-3$, which gives $x > +\frac{1}{3}$ and this does not work.  But for  $x > -1$ we get 
$$\begin{array}{c}
-5(x+1) < x-3 < 2(x-1) \\
6x > -2 \rightarrow x > -\frac{1}{3} \\
3x < +1 \rightarrow x < +\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}
$$
which has solution 
$$
-\frac{1}{3} < x < \frac{1}{3}
$$

On the $t > 0$ branch, we need to solve $2 < \frac{x-3}{x+1} < 5$. We again break this up into two possibilities, $x < -1$ and $x > -1$.

When  $x < -1$ we then get on one side $2(x+1) > x-3$, which gives $x > -2$, and $5(x+1) < x-3$, which gives $x > -5$.  For  $x > -1$ we get $2(x+1) < x-3$, which holds if $x < -5$, which contradicts $x > -1$ so that case does not give any solutions.

Thus the answer combines the two solution regions:

$$
\left( -5 < x < 2 \right) \bigcup \left( -\frac{1}{3} < x < \frac{1}{3} \right)
$$

Comment: very detalied, thanks

Answer (score 10):

Substituting $t=|\frac {x-3}{x+1}|$ will help. Can you see it?

Comment: This is a better substitution than the one suggested by @Elimination, I think

Comment: @MPW, that is because we have the advantage that $(|x|)^{2}=x^{2}$,

Comment: Well, I was thinking that your substitution gives a simple quadratic inequality "$t^2-7t+10<0$", whereas the other substitution gives something about as difficult as the original problem, "$t^2-7|t| + 10 < 0$".

Comment: Also, I should add that we must hope OP is only considering real solutions. Otherwise, we are in trouble, aren't we -- we will have to tread much more carefully in the complex domain since we lose the equality you mentioned (that is, $|z|^2$ need not equal $z^2$ for general $z\in\mathbb C$)

Comment: @MPW, the question is meaningless in the complex domain since order is meaningless in complex numbers.

Comment: No, there can easily be complex solutions to this inequality. For example, if $x=1+2i$, then $\frac{x-3}{x+1}$ is just $i$, and the left side of the inequality is $2$ (a real number). This particular choice of $x$ is not a solution, but it does give a real number on the left side. That's always the interpretation when you have an inequality involving potentially complex numbers--the presence of the inequality implies a requirement that the expressions on both sides are real (but this in itself does *not* require that $x$ be real). In fact, if the inequality were "$>$", my $x$ would work.

Comment: If my quickly scribbled work is right, the complex solutions are precisely $$x=\left(\frac{3-c^2}{1+c^2}\right)+i\left(\frac{4c}{1+c^2}\right)$$ where $c>\frac{-7+\sqrt{89}}{2}$ or $c<\frac{7-\sqrt{89}}{2}$.

Comment: (continued) Note a complex number can only be a solution if the first term in the inequality is real, which means we must have $\frac{x-3}{x+1}$ is either real or pure imaginary (*i.e.,* of the form $ci$ for real $c$). Then you can proceed with the resulting inequality from there, as (I hope correctly) I did.

Comment: how about graphicly sketching?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint (for a start):** $$t = \frac{x-3}{x+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right)^2-7 \left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|+ 10 \lt 0 \Rightarrow \\ \left(\left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|\right)^2-7 \left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|+ 10 \lt 0 $$

$$\Delta=\left(-7\right)^2-4 \cdot 10=49-40=9$$

$$\left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|_{1,2}=\frac{-\left(-7\right) \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{7 \pm \sqrt{9}}{2}=\frac{7 \pm 3}{2}$$

$\left(\left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|\right)^2-7 \left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|+ 10 \lt 0 \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right| \in \left(\frac{7-3}{2},\frac{7+3}{2}\right)=\left(2,5\right)$

$$\left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|\gt 2 \Rightarrow \frac{x-3}{x+1}\lt -2 \text{ OR } \frac{x-3}{x+1}\gt 2 $$
and
$$\left|\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right|\lt 5 \Rightarrow -5\lt \frac{x-3}{x+1}\lt 5 $$

Solve at each case for $x$.

Can you continue?